# Does the flanking provided by Slivers stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I was to play 2 [Sidewinder Slivers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=118908) would the 'All Slivers have flanking' ability stack causing creatures blocking my Slivers to get -2/-2 until the end of the turn or would it gain flanking twice but the second instance has no effect so creatures blocking my Slivers only get -1/-1 until the end of the turn?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flanking is a triggered ability, so it can trigger separately for every instance of the ability that the creature has.  This is ever so slightly different than just giving -2/-2.  When your creature is blocked two abilities go on the stack, each one to give the blocker -1/-1.  The end result is indeed that the blocker ends up with -2/-2, but there are some various corner cases you could create with certain cards where it matters!

NB: You can tell it's a triggered ability because it starts with the magic words "When, Whenever, or At."

Answer (score 11):

**Each instance of Flanking triggers separately.** After the stack resolves, creatures blocking will have -2/-2 until end of turn.

[The Rules](http://magic.wizards.com/en/gameinfo/gameplay/formats/comprehensiverules):

> 702.24. Flanking
>
> 702.24a Flanking is a triggered ability that triggers during the declare blockers step. (See rule 509, "Declare Blockers Step.")
>   "Flanking" means "Whenever this creature becomes blocked by a creature
>   without flanking, the blocking creature gets -1/-1 until end of turn."
>
> 702.24b If a creature has multiple instances of flanking, each triggers separately.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Each sliver will have 2 instances of Flanking. Since those are triggered abilities, each instance will trigger, go to the stack, and resolve separately.